# Bash script to copy folder and contents without one file

Tags: linux, bash, glob, cp, extglob

I'm trying to copy a directories contents without one file. The problem i'm having is that the file is a few folders nested and the extglob operator fails to match.

Assume the following folder structure:

[image]

I would like to copy everything from source, including subfolders and files into dest *except* smu.txt.

I would have thought the following would do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

cp -vr source/!(smu.txt) dest/
```

But it still copies smu.txt.

I also tried the following without success:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globstar

cp -vr source/!(**/smu.txt) dest/
```

It if smu.txt is directly under `../source` it successfully ignores it, but how do I get it to ignore files within subdirectories?

Comment: You can do this with rsync. Google for rsync. `rsync --exclude=...` is the options.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using find?
Maybe this works:

```
$ find -name "source/*!(smu.txt)" -exec cp -vr {} dest/\;
```